# Large performance difference: Using sysdate vs using pre-formatted date

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle9i

Why is there such a huge performance difference between these two queries?

```
-- (89 seconds)
SELECT max(mydate) FROM mytable WHERE eqpid = 'ABCDEFG'
AND mydate < sysdate - 5
```

vs.

```
-- (0.6 seconds)
SELECT max(mydate) FROM mytable WHERE eqpid = 'ABCDEFG'
AND mydate < TO_DATE('05/27/2011 03:13:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') -- 5 days ago
```

Regardless of indexes, it seems that both to_date and sysdate just return "some date value".

Notes: A composite index exists on this table including eqpid and 2 other columns.
An index also exists for mydate. Both are b-tree. There are about 29 million rows.

Why would the optimizer choose such an obviously different (and in one case, awful) plan for these?

Comment: What is the list of columns in the index for `eqpid`?  Is is a combined index with `eqpid` down the list of columns?  If so then Oracle might think that it isn't an efficient type index to use, and so it penalizes that plan.

Comment: @btilly: The composite primary key in this case includes 3 columns: eqpid (varchar2 8 byte), rectype (varchar1 1 byte), serialnobyte (number). It is my understanding that eqpid, the first in the key, can use the index.

Comment: Yeah, it should be able to do so, and did in the second query.  But you clearly have a lot of rows with that eqpid, and it must have shied away from it when it thought it had an alternative.  The optimizer can do strange things.  (But I miss it when I need to make MySQL run complex queries.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jonathan Lewis has written about issues with `sysdate` in 9i; have a look at the 'surprising sysdate' section [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TGSd3pkMx5IC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=jonathan+lewis+surprising+sysdate&source=bl&ots=9lVdlnie9r&sig=CVDQtGGghUMY6WMMcpn8oT9mYKc&hl=en&ei=s7fmTYfzFomXhQe5jp3MCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false), for example. Essentially the arithmetic on `sysdate` seems to confuse the optimizer, so in this case it thinks the index on `mydate` is more selective. This seems like quite an extreme example though. (Originally pointed in this direction from a not-really-related Ask Tom post).

Comment: I am surprised even Oracle let that get through QA.

Comment: +1, I vaguely remembered reading about this but couldn't find the reference ;-)

Comment: Do you mean more selective, instead of less selective?

Comment: @btilly - er, yes. Corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Oracle, but in Postgresql a possible source of ignoring an index is mismatched types. Maybe doing the straight `- 5` makes Oracle think the rhs is numeric. Can you do a cast to date (or whatever is the *exact* type of mydate) on `sysdate - 5`?